# Send ajax request for multiple urls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to trigger 2 emails with different templates for different recipients. I tired to add another url next to url:, however it didn't work. Is there a way to add more that one emailer to ajax request? Your advice is much appreciated. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../wp-admin/emailer.php","../wp-admin/emailer2.php" // add more emailers
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){ return true;}
});
window.location.href = "thank-you";
```

Comment: You can't do that

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that becuase a single AJAX request can only talk to one URL, but you can create multiple AJAX requests for different URLs, and they will do their work simultaneously - you wouldn't need to wait for one to complete before firing off the next one.  So in that case you have to take an `array` where you reserve all the urls.Then you need is `$.each` and the two parameter form of `$.ajax`

```
var urls = ['/url/one','/url/two', ....];

$.each(urls, function(i,u){ 
     $.ajax(u, 
       { type: "POST",
         data: dataString;
         success: function(){
           return true;
         } 
       }
     );
});
window.location.href = "thank-you";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to fire after multiple requests succeed:

```
var req1 = $.post("../wp-admin/emailer.php", dataString);
var req2 = $.post("../wp-admin/emailer2.php", dataString);

$.when(req1,req2).then(function(){
     // all requests succeeded
     window.location.href = "thank-you";
}).fail(function(){
    // oops, something went wrong with at least one of the requests
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the callback for each email and given you will have less than 100 emails, you can use recursion
Eg Show a thank you only when all the emails have been sent successfully

```
var urls=["url1","url2","url3","url4"];
var done=true;
function sendEmails(){

    if(urls.length==0 && done){
        alert("All emails sent successfully");
        return true;
    }else if(urls.length>0 && !done){
        alert("There was an error");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        var url=urls.pop();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){ 
                sendEmails()
            },
            error:function(){
                done=false; 
                sendEmails();
            }
        });
    }
}
sendEmails();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This Methods to Call Multiple URl withb Data....
It also help for future call or Dynamic call in any where in Your code

```
function sendMyAjax(URLAdd,dataString){
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: URLAdd
         data: dataString,
         success: function(){ return true;}
      });
    window.location.href = "thank-you";
    }
};

sendMyAjax("../wp-admin/emailer.php","DataString");
sendMyAjax("../wp-admin/emailer.php","DataString");
```

You Can Use Array for the store URL and Data

Comment: redirect will be called immediately the first time method is called and second won't even have a chance to be called